# OPs can't craft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I'm an OP on my PocketMine server and I get a message to gather more blocks when I try to craft anything. If I de-OP myself I can craft without any problems.

Why do I have to de-OP to craft?

Comment: What, if any, plugins do you have installed?

Comment: @BenMorris armorspawn, random item,timerban, caplimit, realtime, vipslots, netherchests, server mail

Comment: isn't modded games off topic? Anyway What is the message you get?

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic as we don't provide technical support for modded Minecraft.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a specific set of minecraft mods.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the assessment that this is a technical issues question, and as such, I am voting to reopen. [See meta for details](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11015/what-exactly-is-technical-support)

Comment: the meta posted seems to disagree with you, @Unionhawk.

Comment: @Timelord64 No it doesn't. It's ambiguously worded, but [this is more the essence](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11015/what-exactly-is-technical-support#comment33907_11018) rather than classifying this sort of situation as "not working"

Comment: "Does Minecraft currently work? Is it unmodded? If both of those questions come up as no, then I hit the close button"

Comment: @Timelord64 the person you quoted that from was saying that minecraft does work, so why would you quote that? the meta post is agreeing with reopening and Unionhawk's stance.

Comment: I do base that off my interpretation that minecraft is infact not working. I dont necissarily agree with the meta

Comment: @Timelord64 The question quite clearly states that a function in the game doesn't work when the player is a server OP. Not sure how you got that the *game* doesn't work from that.

Answer (score 2):

Since no answers have popped up yet, I would just like to suggest a possible solution in cases like these.

First off, Pocket Edition Minecraft has been updated since the time of this post, so I presume that the Plugins used on the server have also updated since that time.(And most likely, this bug has disappeared form existence)

The problem with not being able to craft was quite obviously caused by either: PocketMine(Very Highly Doubtful, since I never had this problem) or by a Plugin(Highest Possibility). Again, this issue was probably fixed by the time I am writing this.

In all likeliness, the crafting error was caused by a Plugin.(Probably poorly written, or bad perms) What I would do when I came across a Plugin problem, was to disable all plugins, and test the issue occurring plugin by plugin. When the plugin causing the issue is found, the best option would be to go and contact the Plugin Dev, to see if the issue could be resolved. If the issue couldn't be resolved, You would either have to simply live with having to de-op yourself to craft, or disable the plugin.

IMO, topics like this should be locked. It is the server owner's responsibility to edit or remove faulty plugins. When I ran a server, I did all of the maintenance by myself, which did include occasionally contacting devs.